# Import board package In Julia

Tags: package, julia

I am new to Julia and am busy developing a search board game so i needed to use board package.how do I import or use board in Julia?

Ex: In python that would be import board

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install and use any Python package in Julia, try this:

```
using PyCall
run(`$(PyCall.python) -m pip install board`)
board = pyimport("board")
b = board.Board((3, 3))
b[0, 0] = "X"
b[1, 0] = "O"
```

However it would be much more efficient to port that code to Julia.
This should be very easy since the `Board` can be just a Julia `Matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be a Julia package that does what the Python board package does. Based on my search, one does not exits. I suggest checking out: https://julialang.org/packages for the resources to search existing registered Julia Packages.